# Convert the end() iterator to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

To get to the point: is the following safe ?

```
vector<int> v;
int const* last = &*v.end(); 
// last is never dereferenced
```

My concern is that the trick to get a plain old pointer from an iterator forces to dereference the end() iterator, which is not valid... even if it is just to take the pointer back!

**Backgroud**: I am trying to create a collection of entries indexed by arbitrary types (especially integers and pointer to objects).

```
template<class IT>
/// requires IT implements addition (e.g. int, random-access iterator)
class IndexingFamily {
    public:
        using IndexType = IT;

        IndexingFamily(IndexType first, IndexType last);
        int size() const;
        IndexType operator[](int i) const;
    private:
        IndexType first;
        IndexType last;
};

template<class IT> IndexingFamily<IT>::
IndexingFamily(IndexType first, IndexType last) 
    : first(first)
    , last(last) {}

template<class IT> auto IndexingFamily<IT>::
size() const -> int {
    return last-first;
}

template<class IT> auto IndexingFamily<IT>::
operator[](int i) const -> IndexType {
    return first+i;
}

template<class IT, class ET>
struct IndexedEntry {
    using IndexType = IT;
    using EntryType = ET;

    IndexType index;
    EntryType entry;
};

template<class IT, class ET>
class CollectionOfEntries {
    public:
        using IndexType = IT;
        using EntryType = ET;

        /// useful methods
    private:
        IndexingFamilyType indexingFamily;
        vector<EntryType> entries;
};


struct MyArbitraryType {};


int main() {
    MyArbitraryType obj0, obj1, obj2;
    vector<MyArbitraryType> v = {obj0,obj1,obj2};

    using IndexType = MyArbitraryType const*;
    IndexingFamily<IndexType> indexingFamily(&*v.begin(),&*v.end());

    using EntryType = double;
    using IndexedEntryType = IndexedEntry<IndexType,EntryType>;
    IndexedEntry entry0 = {&obj0,42.};
    IndexedEntry entry1 = {&obj1,43.};
    vector<IndexedEntryType> entries = {entry0,entry1};

    CollectionOfEntries coll = {indexingFamily,entries};

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, "a collection of entries indexed by arbitrary types" sounds a lot like the definition of a map...

Comment: `v.data() + v.size()` would be safer.

Comment: You *are* aware that `end()` refers to the element *beyond* the last one, right?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes but in my real case, a map would not help in the way data is processed

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, Ideally, I'd want vector<T>::const_iterator == T const*

Answer (score 3):

Dereferencing an `end()` iterator gives undefined behaviour, with any standard container.

For a vector you can get a pointer corresponding to the `end()` iterator using

```
pointer_to_end = v.empty() ? 0 : (&(*v.begin()) + v.size());
```

or

```
pointer_to_end = v.data() + v.size();   // v.data() gives null is size is zero
```

The check of `v.empty()` is needed since, if `v` is empty, `v.begin() == v.end()`.    For C++11 or later, use of `nullptr` instead of `0` in the above is often considered preferable.

Comment: "*if `v` is empty, `v.begin() == v.end()`*" - why would you thus want `0` as the result here?

Comment: I understand that, but it's still not clear why you'd want that rather than `v.begin()` as the result.

Comment: `(&(*v.begin()) + v.size())` (which equates to `&*v.begin()`) rather?

Comment: if `v.begin() == v.end()` then dereferencing `v.begin()` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  That will also require more general changes to the OP's code, though.

Comment: Your answer is ok except for that empty case: pointers past the end of the last element where chosen to treat empty ranges in a uniform way, so it kind of defeats the point...

Comment: That's a problem with the design of your collection.  I simply responded to your question as asked.

Comment: Your second piece of code is ok, I'd like to accept your answer. But I don't like the first piece of code at all because for an empty collection we don't have first==last anymore.

Comment: Only if you don't manage the pointers consistently.  Use `pointer_to_beginning = v.empty()? 0 : &(*v.begin())` in the first case, and `pointer_to_beginning = v.data()` in the second.    A vectors iterators are invalidated whenever it is resized anyway - the same goes for pointers to first and last element.   As long as the pointers to first and last elements are kept in sync, either option I gave is a valid way to get the end pointer - and will work with empty containers as well as non-empty ones.

Answer (score 1):

The iterator returned by member function `end()` "points" after the last element of a vector. You may not dereference it. Otherwise the program will have undefined behavior.

You can get the corresponding pointer the following way

```
vector<int> v;
int const *last = v.data() + v.size();
```

If you want to use the iterator returned by the member function end() you can write

```
vector<int> v;
int const *last = v.data() + std::distance( v.begin(), v.end() );
```

Take into account that member function data() returns a raw pointer of the memory extent occupied by vector's data.